# How can I install chromedriver in AWS Cloud9?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium-chromedriver, aws-cloud9

#### environment

aws ec2

```
ec2-user:~ $ which python
alias python='python36'
        /usr/bin/python36
```

```
ec2-user:~ $ pip install chromedriver
Requirement already satisfied: chromedriver in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2.24.1)
```

```
ec2-user:/usr/local/bin $ ls
chromedriver
```

#### question

How can I proceed chromeDriver.py and get a wanted result?

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver_linux64.zip
--2019-11-18 03:14:39--  https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.70/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Resolving chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)... 172.217.25.112, 2404:6800:4004:80b::2010
Connecting to chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com (chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com)|172.217.25.112|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5527671 (5.3M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘chromedriver_linux64.zip’

chromedriver_linux64.zip   100%[=======================================>]   5.27M  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

‘chromedriver_linux64.zip’ saved [5527671/5527671]
```

chromeDriver.py

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

browser.get("https://www.google.com")

browser.save_screenshot("screen.png")

sleep(5)

browser.close()
```

This is a result.

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ python3 chromeDriver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chromeDriver.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 88, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Is it correct to read selenium from the path "$HOME:/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages" ?

Comment: What have you tried? The error is: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
I'd be willing to be dollars to donuts the account you are running the script under doesn't have permission to the chromedriver. Set those permissions with something like chmod or run it under a different account (like a root user) to see if it works, and adjust permissions accordingly

Comment: Thank you for replying!
I gave sudo command to /usr/local/bin/chromedriver, but I still have a problem...
I would like you to help me!!

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: I don't get it yet.